# Adding multiple comments to a child in firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add comments on a child with Firebase.
But how can I raise the number of the comment?

```
 let object: [String: Any] = [
            "name": "testname",
            "comment": "hi how are you"]
        database.child("commentsAreStoredHere/commentOne").setValue(object)
```

With this code I would add comment number one on the child commentsAreStoredHere. But how can I add comment number two?

Do I need an if else statement? Something like: Check if Comment Number one exists. If yes check if comment number two exists and add comment two.... But this would not be good code.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the Firebase documentation on [appending data to a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data), you'll want to use `childByAutoId` for that. So:

```
database.child("commentsAreStoredHere").childByAutoId().setValue(object)
```

For more on why not to use sequential, numerical values as the keys, have a look at [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used childByAutoID() now. But when I try to get the last 4 comments I still get some randomly picked. I use this to get the last comments: database.child("something").queryLimited(toLast: 4).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
                return

Comment: You'll want to use `orderByKey()` in there at the very least. Even if it doesn't fix he problem, you should be explicit about the ordering you want. Aside from that: as soon as you do `snapshot.value` you get back a dictionary, and the keys in there are by definition unordered. To process the results in order, loop over `snapshot.children` and process each result in turn.